# Problems with scala's dot-free syntax

Tags: scala

Why the following does not work:

```
<a x="2" /> \ "@x" text toDouble
<console>:8: error: not found: value toDouble
```

and this does?

```
(<a x="2" /> \ "@x" text).toDouble
```

Comment: Use of postfix method call syntax (e.g. `toDouble` on the end with no dot) is not recommended except in certain DSLs. The reason being that it can cause problems with semicolon inference depending on what's on the next line. So keep the parentheses and the dot.

Comment: This is scala. We don't need extra semicolons or parentheses if it can be successfully compiled without them. Have to look ahead, not back (sorry about throwing in some philosophy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because it is interpreted as

```
 (<a x="2" /> \ "@x").text(toDouble)
```

Have you tried

```
 (<a x="2" /> \ "@x" text) toDouble
```

(without ever having used scala...)

Comment: As far as I know, your second example is equal to my second example (only the dot is omitted). What I really wanted is to get rid of the parentheses.

Comment: Yes, but probably the dot-free syntax will only allow you to replace dots with whitespace, not omit parantheses - it's not called the parantheses-free syntax.

Comment: Yet it allows me to omit parentheses from (<a x="2" /> \ "@x").text

Comment: Yes, but that is just a side effect, not a general rule, I guess.

Comment: @Rogach Roughly spoken: `a m b` gets translated to `a.m(b)`, not to `a.m.b`, or else the dot-free notation would only be useable with methods without parameters. You either have to use dots or parentheses to solve your case.

Comment: @Anonymouse Can you replace your first line with `(<a x="2" /> \ "@x").text(toDouble)` so that you have the correct interpretation?